# Can I run NM-B cable along exposed studs instead of through them?

Tags: wiring

I have an unfinished room and on one wall it is open on the back of the studs where there is plumbing and duct work running the length of the room.

Can I strap six 12/2's together and strap them to the back of the studs instead of running through the studs?

Comment: I believe you'll run into derate rules if you bundle 6. 3 2s or 2 3s should save that headache.

Comment: @Brian When you say "back of the stud", do you mean on the side of the stud (the wide 6" to 10" part), or the "bottom" of it which is around 2 inches wide?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue you likely will encounter is an inspectors determination of "protected from physical damage where necessary...", and without a photo nobody wants to stick their toes out to get assaulted.

Bundling usually implies cable ties, if cable ties are used they must be "listed and identified for securement and support".

Bundling for 24+", through a sealed penetration, or in contact with thermal insulation is subject to derating. The maximum number of conductors subject to derating while maintaining the 20A maximum small conductor limit is 9 current carrying conductors: 9 requires derate to 70% of the 30A rating of 90°C rated #12 NM-B allowing 4 @ 12/2 cables per bundle.

Comment: This would be considered bundling and flagged by an inspector usually over 3 wires will get flagged derate or not, I quit fighting that battle a long time ago. Through a nipple under 24” not the same as strapping together similar to going through a bored hole.